# A clue is needed to solve a rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

This rebus has me stumped.  Anyone have any clues to the solution.

> know know 
>   know know 
>   Know know 
>   Know to know

Comment: The rebus should have two "know" on 3 lines and then the 4th line is "know to know". Sorry it didn't come out this way in my question.

Comment: "No one knows to enforce ..." ? (there's no single "know" + "to" in 4th) I dunno.

Comment: Are the capital letters significant?

Answer (score 15):

I wonder if the original formatting was more columnar, so that two stacks of "knows" were separated by the "to", like so:

```
know    know  
know    know  
know    know  
know to know
```

If it were, then it could be

> "nose to nose", with the rebus forming "knows to knows".

Comment: This seems likely. +1

Comment: @Rubio - thanks for the edit, my apologies for not using spoilers.

Comment: Your answer might be correct, but [this is the original formatting, as posted](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/c9f5d2af-0110-4381-a467-8d3d0ee4bfb1/view-source).

Answer (score 4):

This may well be the puzzle as I have seen elsewhere; slightly different in its format:

```
  know  know
  know  know
  know  know
->know  know
```

which of course is

> the last to(two) know

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted it as

> '7 knows to 8'; As in 'The number 8 follows 7', because there are 7 'knows' before the "to" followed by the 8th 'know'.

I do think

> "nose to nose"

is probably the correct answer though. Well done.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Take the [Site Tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), check out some other questions and their answers, and see how we roll here.  Nice to see you and hope to see you again and again!